# PHP Unit Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, phpunit, strtotime

I'm using strtotime() in PHP to get the days of a week (I made a calendar, with different views, so it changes).
PHP Unit gives me the warning of Array to string conversion whenever I try this:

```
$monday  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sunday . '+ 1 day'));
```

$sunday is a variable that I get this way:

```
public function GetWeekRange($date) {
        $ts = strtotime($date);
        $start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
        return date('Y-m-d', $start);
}
```

and $date is a string in the format 'YYYY-mm-dd'

I'm not sure why I get this error, the code works just fine, but the test gives that warning, and it's going to give a warning on my environment where all the different projects are shown (red/green depending on whether there's a failure or not).

Thanks,

Fer

Comment: Nothing there causes that error.  Keep looking.

Comment: GetWeekRange is a poor name for this function given it doesn't return an array.

Comment: yea, i have to change it, it used to return an array with the first day of the week (sunday) and the last (saturday). but that gave me a different warning: undefined offset: 1 and undefined offset: 0

Comment: now updated to GetFirstDayOfWeek

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake: I updated the function to return only one string, but the mocked value I kept as an array.

My bad.